# Javascript alerts that expire with potential extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have javascript alerts that appear, I would like each alert to disappear after 3 seconds, however I've only been able to get them to all vanish at once, and then I can't make any more alerts.

I would also like that if a user hovers over an alert, that this resets the 3 seconds until the alert disappears.

Right now I'm using the `setTimeout` function, and I'm 99% sure that is my problem, I think I need to restructure things to use some jquery delay or other wait function, but I'm unsure how to do that and still get the the behavior I'm looking for.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="site">
  <div class="btn btn-danger">Red Alert!</div>
  <div id="alerts" data-count="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript code is:

```
$('.btn-danger').click(function(){
  var count = $('#alerts').data('count');
  var alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-dismiss="alert">' + count +'</div>';
  var a = $('#alerts').append(alert)
  setTimeout(function() { $(a).hide(); }, 3000);
  count += 1;
  $('#alerts').data('count', count);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bradygp/odq3qjaw/7/)

[Final JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bradygp/x0r9qcu8/4/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason all your alerts are vanishing at once and you can't add new ones is this code:

```
var alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-dismiss="alert">' + count +'</div>';
var a = $('#alerts').append(alert)
setTimeout(function() { $(a).hide(); }, 3000);
```

You're expecting the variable `a` to be a jQuery object for the individual alert, but it isn't. It's the entire `$('#alerts')` object, i.e. the *parent* of the alerts. That's because `.append()` returns the object you're appending to, not the object you're appending. In other words, like many jQuery functions, `.append()` returns "the thing to the left of the dot" so it is chainable.

So when the timer runs out, you aren't just hiding the individual alert, but the parent container, thus hiding them all. Your code still creates alert elements successfully after that, but you can't see them because the parent is hidden.

What I would do instead is create the jQuery object you want at the beginning, by wrapping the HTML string in a `$()` call. We'll call that variable `$alert`. And while we're at it, since `$('#alerts')` appears several places in the code, we'll give that a variable too:

```
$('.btn-danger').click(function(){
  var $alerts = $('#alerts');
  var count = $alerts.data('count');
  var $alert = $(
    '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-dismiss="alert">' +
      count +
    '</div>'
  );
  $alerts.append($alert);
  setTimeout(function() { $alert.hide(); }, 3000);
  count += 1;
  $alerts.data('count', count);
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odq3qjaw/10/).

To reset the timeout when the mouse moves over one of your alerts, you just need to save the `setTimeout()` return value in a local variable, and when there's a `mousemove` event, call `clearTimeout()` on that variable and start a fresh timer, like this:

```
$('.btn-danger').click(function() {
  var timer;
  var $alerts = $('#alerts');
  var count = $alerts.data('count');
  var $alert = $(
    '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-dismiss="alert">' +
      count +
    '</div>'
  );
  $alerts.append($alert);
  startTimer();
  $alert.on( 'mousemove', startTimer );
  count += 1;
  $alerts.data('count', count);

  function startTimer() {
    clearTimeout( timer );
    timer = setTimeout( function() {
      $alert.hide();
    }, 3000 );
  }
});
```

Here's [this version of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odq3qjaw/11/).

My last suggestion for now... Unless you really need to store the `count` value in the `data-count` DOM attribute, I would suggest simply using a JavaScript variable for that:

```
(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
    ++count;
    var timer;
    var $alerts = $('#alerts');
    var $alert = $(
      '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-dismiss="alert">' +
        count +
      '</div>'
    );
    $alerts.append($alert);
    startTimer();
    $alert.on( 'mousemove', startTimer );

    function startTimer() {
      clearTimeout( timer );
      timer = setTimeout( function() {
        $alert.hide();
      }, 3000 );
    }
  });
})();
```

So here is my [final fiddle for the night](https://jsfiddle.net/odq3qjaw/12/), along with a runnable snippet:

```js
(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
    count += 1;
    var timer;
    var $alerts = $('#alerts');
    var $alert = $(
      '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-dismiss="alert">' +
        count +
      '</div>'
    );
    $alerts.append($alert);
    startTimer();
    $alert.on( 'mousemove', startTimer );

    function startTimer() {
      clearTimeout( timer );
      timer = setTimeout( function() {
        $alert.hide();
      }, 3000 );
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
#site {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#alerts {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="site">
  <div class="btn btn-danger">Red Alert!</div>
  <div id="alerts" data-count="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

And with that, I will leave you with a challenge. If you try this out, you'll probably notice a couple of things that aren't ideal. One is that you have to keep the mouse moving to prevent a timeout. Instead of using `mousemove` as I did in this code, you could use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. And related to that, it seems that it would probably be nicer to halt *all* the timeouts if the mouse is over *any* of the alerts. Otherwise the alert you have the mouse over may slide out from underneath it when another alert is cleared. That shouldn't be hard to do either.

Happy hacking!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a look at this Michael, and for your input at the bottom. I hadn't considered halting all timeouts while the mouse is over any alert, but that is a good idea. Beats my idea of adding an icon to the alert to allow the user to anchor the alert to the page, because they would only have 3 seconds to decide and perform this action. Thanks for all your help!